# Digit sum relation between powers of $11$ and powers of $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is this IGMO question of $2022$. It wants you to find the sum of $n$ that fulfill
$$
s(11^n)=2^n
$$
where $s(x)$ is the digit sum.

---

Computing the first $n$'s gives always correct statements until $n=5$.

There is a Connection between $2^n$ and Pascals Triangle and also between $11^n$ and Pascals Triangle but I am not sure how to prove this statement. Any hints would be apreciated.

I also tried writing $(10+1)^n$ with binomial theorem but it got me nowhere.

Comment: It certainly isn't true for every $n$ that $s(11^n)=2^n$.

Comment: @RobertShore I take it that's why the question asks for the sum over all $n$ which *do* satisfy such, so the answer is probably not $\infty$.

Comment: Yeah I had in my head that for every $n$ it is divisible. It is obvious that it does not work for every number.

Comment: "it is always divisible by $2$ I think" $s(11^9)=53$ is odd.

Comment: $s(11^n)<9 \times \lceil n\log_{10}(11)\rceil$  so you can get a bound on $n$.

Answer (score 6):

Writing $11^n = (10+1)^n$ is the right step, because you can get the expression:
$$ 11^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} 10^k.$$
It is tempting to say that the digit sum is therefore $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$, which is equal to $2^n$ (you can find many proofs of this online), but alas, this only works when each ${n \choose k }$ is less than or equal to $9$. If it's over, then the digit carries over. This explains why $s(11^n) = 2^n$ for $n=1,2,3,4$.

So you might guess that it stops being true for $n \ge 5$. Let's think about the case $n =5$. You have an expansion of
$$11^5 = 1\times 10^0 + 5\times 10^1 + 10 \times 10^2 + 10 \times 10^3 + 5 \times 10^4 + 1 \times 10^5,$$
and if you add up all the binomial coefficients you get $1 + 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 1 = 2^5 = 32$. However, the $10$ "carries over", so to get from $32$ to the digit sum, you have to subtract the $10$ and then add $1$. This happens twice, so the digit sum is $32-2\times 9 = 14$. Indeed, $11^5 = 161051$, and $1+6+1+0+5+1 = 14$.

In general, whenever a binomial coefficient is greater than or equal to $10$, then you'll have to start with $2^n$ and subtract a strictly positive number to get to the digit sum. This shows that $s(11^n) = 2^n$ does not hold for $n \ge 5$. Hence, the sum of all the $n$ that fulfil the equality is $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$.

Comment: Excellent answer.  (+1)